# Calling method from javascript in MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to call a controller method from Javascript. I used the following code:

```
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Run" onclick="RunEXE"/>
```

I want to write the javascript to call the below function in controller.

```
public void Run(UserProgram userProgram)
    {
        SaveAndCompile(userProgram);
    }
```

Can anyone provide me the javascript to call the function.

Comment: Take a look at [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/)

Comment: You want javascript or jQuery?

Comment: @Murali Murugesan- anyone. But i just want to call that function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just call a function like that. What you need to understand is that javascript runs on the client, and your function is on the server. What you need to do is make a request to the server, just like you would when loading a page, so for this you need an `Action` (make sure it is a POST action as we will be "posting" the request). This action can be as short as just calling the function you need:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RunAction(string option1)
{
    //if needed, you can use the "option1" value to determine the UserProgram to pass
    UserProgram userProgram = new UserProgram();
    Run(userProgram);

    //you can return a JSON reuslt that you can evaluate back at the client
    return Json(new { @Success = true, @MyString = "a string" });
}
```

Then you want to use ajax to call the function from the client (javascript), for this I would recommend [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) as it makes things much easier using [`post`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.post('@Url.Action("RunAction", "MyController")',
      {
         option1: "some optional value"
      },
      function (data) {
          alert("success!");
          //here you have access to your JSON result via data, for example:
          //data.Success = true
          //data.MyString = "a string"
      }
);
```

Comment: May i know what is about "program" in your post

Comment: @Balaji: "program" is an example of a value you can pass to determine what the `UserProgram` should be, if you don't need it then remove it

Comment: I just want to get a string value from controller function to jquery. Is it possible

Comment: @Balaji: I edited my answer to show an example of how to return a string value to the client

Comment: But when i am entering the action in jquery its showing cannot resolve action.

Comment: Its working.. But still i want to know how to assign values to a class property from jquery.

Comment: @Balaji: Sorry been on lunch, but glad to hear it is working. You can't set properties of a class for a few reasons but there are work arounds to get the desired result, I would recommend you start a whole new question for this...

Comment: Can u tell me how to get the "@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.FileName)" value in jquery.

Comment: @Balaji: You can just use `var fileName = "@Model.FileName";` or if you already have it in a textbox: `var fileName = $("#myTextBoxId").val();`

Answer (score 3):

You can use Ajax here. jQuery ajax is very flexible and easy

Then

prepare your data to post

```
var myData={};// this is similar to your C# class UserProgram structure
myData.property1=value1; //etc

jQuery.ajax{( 
url: '/controllerName/Run/', // or '@Url.Action("Run", "ControllerName")'
type: 'post',
data:{userProgram:myData},
success: function (data) { jQuery('#container').html(data); }
)};
```

or shorthand

```
 $.post('/controllerName/Run/',{userProgram:myData}, function(result){});
```

Comment: But add reference to jQuery file first

Comment: @Murali Murugesan - Can u please elaborate sir,,

Comment: @gaurav: Unless the OP has removed the reference explicitly, it's very likely already in his ASP.NET MVC template.

Comment: @Murali Murugesan: Can u tell me how to get the "@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.FileName)" value in jquery.

Comment: @Balaji, add id `Html.TextboxFor(m => m.FileName,{@id='txtFileName'})` and in jQuery `$('#txtFileName').val()` to get file name

Answer (score 3):

Try this using JQuery:

```
function RunEXE() {
   $.post('@Url.Action("Run", "ControllerName")',
      {
         userProgram: "WhatEver" //The parameter you want to pass to your action
      },
      function (data) {
         //Code for what to do with the result.
      })
};
```

Comment: I voted this one up over the other for the Url helper method to get the address of the method.

Comment: @krillgar, if the developer moves to js to a separate `.js` file? @Url.Action will not work :)

Comment: Of course it won't. However, if the routing engine changes the way that the URL is structured, you don't need to worry about changing it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Normal AJAX method as::

On the Server side(i.e. In Controller) you are using some class/Model like `'UserProgram'`

I don't know what are the Properties in that class but I have assumed it as::

```
   public class UserProgram
    {
         public long   ID{get;set}
         public string Name{get;set}
    }
```

this Model fields should be based on your Model that you have to pass into your AJAX code as::

```
var myData={ID:1,Name:"RJ"};

    $.ajax{( 
        type: 'post',
        url: '/controllerName/Run'
        data:{UserProgram:myData},
        success: function (data) {
                                  $('#container').empty();
                                  $('#container').html(data); 
                                  }
        )};
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the full description on using ajax calls in ASP.net MVC using jQuery please refer to:

http://bobcravens.com/2009/11/ajax-calls-to-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-using-jquery/