# How to access value to encrypt the value in c# using jQuery in mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

In jQuery I have a function that gets an id that i want to encrypt the date in mvc method, in mvc we can access the coding in html view page itself. in that how to add jQuery function data in that one method

My jQuery function

```
function Redirect(id) {

    var propertyidconvert = '@Utility.Utilities.Commonfunction.Encrypt(id, "PropertyId")';
        alert(propertyidconvert);

}
```

I have a C# method to encrypt the data, but I am unable to add id value, showing error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling method from javascript in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350612/calling-method-from-javascript-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run C# methods during JavaScript runtime.  By the time your JS runs, the view has already been built and rendered by C# and is no longer in the scope of .NET MVC.

To accomplish this, you either have to make an AJAX request back to the server and then receive the encrypted response in JS, or encrypt your data directly in JS.

Comment: Ya got it boss , Thank you

Comment: @Aniket close vote would be way more appropriate... There is not much value in repeating the same statement many times, especially if you are not trying to farm rep.